# Supertabular breaks page too early

Tags: page-breaking, supertabular

I am using supertabular and am having two issues. Firstly, it starts the table on a new column (except for the caption which is weird), and secondly, it breaks too early on the page. Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Here is the code around my issue:

```
Rows in the table highlighted yellow indicate traditional partition methods, those highlighted blue indicate NP ideal solutions, and those highlighted pink represent partitions from the SNN.
```

\begin{center}
\tablecaption{Results from simulations}
\tablefirsthead{%
\toprule
\tbsp # Nodes & Partition Type & Time &Cut & Energy & Modularity \
\midrule}
\tablehead{%
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\small\sl continued from previous page}\
\midrule
\tbsp # Nodes & Partition Type & Time & Cut & Energy & Modularity \
\midrule}
\tabletail{%
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\small\sl continued on next page}\
\bottomrule}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\label{tab:results}

\begin{supertabular}{@{} l l l l l l @{}}

```
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{9} 
                   & kernighan-lin & 473.26 \textmu s & -11 & 17 & 0.170 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman  & 2.01 ms & -7 & 20 & 0.180 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 46.04 ms & -11 & 19 & 0.186 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 46.04 ms & -7 & 20 & 0.180 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 46.04 ms & -11 & 19 & 0.186 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 1.46 ns & -7 & 15 & 0.125 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 1.46 ns & -11 & 16 & 0.186 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 1.46 ns & -11 & 17 & 0.170 \\  
 \addlinespace   
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{18} 
                   & kernighan-lin & 715.02 \textmu s & -60 & 83 & 0.284 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 29.86 ms & -64 & 89 & 0.306 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 72.48 s & -64 & 89 & 0.305 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 72.48 s & 32 & 101 & 0.149 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 72.48 s & -64 & 89 & 0.305 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 5.83 ns & -32 & 67 & 0.245 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 5.83 ns & -32 & 73 & 0.183 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 5.83 ns & -36 & 73 & 0.208 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#3 & 5.83 ns & -44 & 74 & 0.247 \\ 
 \addlinespace  
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{20} 
                   & kernighan-lin & 979.42 \textmu s & -74 & 85 & 0.203 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 44.43 ms & -82 & 85 & 0.224 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 7.20 ns & -42 & 67 & 0.170 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 7.20 ns & -46 & 70 & 0.160 \\ 
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 7.20 ns & -58 & 74 & 0.184 \\ 
 \addlinespace    
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{22} 
                   & metis & 1.64 ms & -92 & 91 & 0.177 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & kernighan-lin & 1.61 ms & -92 & 89 & 0.177 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 84.34 ms & 180 & 101 & -0.00296 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 2.09 ks & -92 & 93 & 0.178 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 2.09 ks & -36 & 101 & 0.124 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 2.09 ks & -92 & 93 & 0.178 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 8.71 ns & -76 & 81 & 0.152 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 8.71 ns & -76 & 81 & 0.152 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 8.71 ns & -88 & 88 & 0.169 \\ 
 \addlinespace
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{24}
                   & kernighan-lin & 1.32 ms & -104 & 108 & 0.173 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 156.77 ms & -104 & 104 & 0.178 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 8.58 ks & -108 & 108 & 0.18 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 8.58 ks & -44 & 126 & 0.133 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 8.58 ks & -108 & 108 & 0.18 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 10.37 ns & -96 & 100 & 0.166 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 10.37 ns & -96 & 100 & 0.166 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 10.37 ns & -100 & 103 & 0.172 \\ 
 
 %\addlinespace
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{24} 
                   & metis & 1.36 ms  & -120 & 153 & 0.306  \\* % no page break at this line
 \rowcolor{yellow} & kernighan-lin & 15.03 ms & -120 & 153 & 0.306 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 113.37 ms & -104 & 142 & 0.272  \\ 
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 11.05 ks & -120 & 150 & 0.306  \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 11.05 ks & 76 & 178 & 0.125  \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 11.05 ks & -120 & 150 & 0.306  \\ 
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 1.44 ns & -84 & 160 & 0.234 \\ 
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 1.44 ns & -104 & 163 & 0.287  \\ 
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 1.44 ns & -116 & 157 & 0.3  \\ 
 \addlinespace 
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{25}
                   & kernighan-lin & 56.65 ms & -131 & 121 & 0.202 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 547.38 ms & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 19.97 ks & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 19.97 ks & -59 & 138 & 0.147 \\
 \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 19.97 ks & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 11.25 ns & -103 & 106 & 0.177 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#3 & 11.25 ns &  -87 & 103 & 0.155 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#4 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\ 
 \addlinespace 
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{35} 
                   & kernighan-lin & 1.66 ms & -233 & 324 & 0.294 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 584.88 ms & -185 & 364 & 0.274 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 22.05 ns & -157 & 269 & 0.269 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 22.05 ns &  -93 & 251 & 0.218 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 22.05 ns & -117 & 252 & 0.255 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#3 & 22.05 ns & -105 & 250 & 0.241 \\ 
 \addlinespace
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{50}
                   & kernighan-lin & 2.02 ms & -356 & 770 & 0.348 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 776.80 ms & -8 & 556 & 0.269 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 45.00 ns &  92 & 522 & 0.240 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 45.00 ns & 108 & 520 & 0.225 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 45.00 ns &  68 & 545 & 0.200 \\ 
 \addlinespace
 \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{50} 
                   & metis & 2.93 ms & -488 & 676 & 0.286 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & kernighan-lin & 2.65 ms & -480 & 669 & 0.286 \\
 \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 3.15 s  & -424 & 604 & 0.273 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 45.00 ns & -400 &  592 & 0.266 \\
 \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 45.00 ns & -444 &  611 & 0.282 \\
```

\end{supertabular}
\end{center}

Overall the simulated Josephson junctions did a really good job partitioning graphs with this method. Even up to 50 node graphs, the SNN was able to do essentially as well as traditional methods and was not far off ideal solutions.

\subsection{Scaling}

Here is what it looks like for me:

[image]

[image]